# Ralink 3090 wireless connects but is slow and unstable on an Ideapad S205

Tags: wireless, 12.10, lenovo, ralink, ideapad

I am using the **Lenovo Ideapad S205** and **Ubuntu 12.10** (32bit). The netbook has a built in **Ralink 3090** wireless card.

The problem is: Wifi does actually work, but network speeds are extremly slow and unstable. I am runnnig on a 32.000 DSL connection and I only get about 50KB/s with my wireless in Ubuntu. To make things worse; it slows down my entire internet router and network connection, forcing me to reset the router in order to bring this situation back to normal speeds again. This issue does not happen on Windows 7.

**My question:** How can I fix this? I read that the S205 @default uses the Open Source wireless driver for my chipset. How can I download and safely install the prop. drivers for my wireless chipset?

Thank you for your time and support - I appreciate it.

Oranges

Comment: Anyone? I really need some help on this, because I need this laptop to work on every day via WLAN. :(

Comment: This is a bug as found by the OP: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1020081

Answer (score 2):

Try using ndiswrapper to install Windows XP drivers (not the installer, the .inf files). That's how I use my Ralink wifi, since the driver present in Ubuntu also makes my connection too slow, unacceptably slow.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of frustration, trying stuff mentioned in the wildest parts of the internet, reinstalling and trying to find an easy solution, I find this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1020081

It seems I am not the only one with this bug/problem (see comment section in the link provided above).