# Ralink RT3090 wifi hard-blocked on IdeaPad S205

Tags: 14.04, wireless, lenovo, ralink

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.3 on someone's IdeaPad S205. Ever since booting from live USB, WiFi wasn't available, saying it was "disabled by hardware switch".

Yes, I have rebooted a couple of times, toggled the hardware switch, toggles the BIOS switch.

Some console:

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
[...]
  *-network DEAKTIVIERT
       Beschreibung: Kabellose Verbindung
       Produkt: RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       Hersteller: Ralink corp.
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:03:00.0
       Logischer Name: wlan0
       Version: 00
       Seriennummer: 94:39:e5:54:23:e3
       Breite: 32 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       Konfiguration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=3.19.0-26-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       Ressourcen: irq:18 memory:f0100000-f010ffff

$ rfkill list
0: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

Hardware switch *actually disabled*

```
$ rfkill list
0: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

I've tried installing `rt3290sta`, but that makes it disappear altogether:

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
[...]
  *-network UNGEFORDERT
       Beschreibung: Network controller
       Produkt: RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       Hersteller: Ralink corp.
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:03:00.0
       Version: 00
       Breite: 32 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       Konfiguration: latency=0
       Ressourcen: memory:f0100000-f010ffff

$ rfkill list
0: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Other things I tried without success: [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/206172/346573), `rfkill unblock all` in all variations, [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/127236/346573), [IDE instead of AHCI](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-U-and-S-Series-Notebooks/S205-Wireless-connection-will-not-activate-on-Win7-64bit/td-p/695643)

Long story short: **No matter what I do, the card pretends to be hardware disabled.**

**EDIT**

```
$ sudo dmidecode | grep 'System Information' -A8
System Information
    Manufacturer: LENOVO
    Product Name: 10383EG
    Version: Ideapad S205
    Serial Number: [...]
    UUID: [...]
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: System SKU Number Unknown
    Family: IDEAPAD
```

Comment: This can be fixed easily. But are you sure that there is no hardware wireless switch?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `sudo dmidecode | grep 'System Information' -A8` terminal command.

Comment: There certainly *is* a hardware switch. It's just on. And it's not broken, the OS that was installed before (MS W10) could connect to wireless alright.

Answer (score 0):

Some genius made [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~markus-tisoft/+archive/ubuntu/rt3090) featuring `rt5390sta` driver at version `2.4.0.4` which after a couple of restarts finally made the WiFi work. *(The download they reference at the official Ralink website doesn't seem to exist anymore)*

It isn't maintained anymore and the kernel module build throws a bunch of warnings, made the thing work though, so whatever.

I recommened adding this line to your sources, offering the latest version, intended for `natty`:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/markus-tisoft/rt3090/ubuntu natty main
```

You then need to

```
sudo apt-get install rt5390-dkms
```

and add these lines to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`:

```
blacklist rt2800pci
blacklist rt2800lib
blacklist rt2x00usb
blacklist rt2x00pci
blacklist rt2x00lib
blacklist rt2860sta
blacklist rt3090sta
```

...or read [my source](http://www.techytalk.info/ubuntu/ralink-wireless/) for solving this.

**EDIT** Okay, I lied. It stopped working a few minutes later. Had to give up on Ubuntu on that machine unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same issue. It seems that the solution is to rearrange the boot-order in the BIOS, such that it will try to boot from "PCI LAN. Realtek..." first.

This may explain why Wifi worked from Live-USB in case your boot-order is such that "USB" comes after "PCI Lan".

You may find this solution as a note in the answer to [Cant install ubuntu 12.04, 14.04 64bit on my lenovo s205](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627629/cant-install-ubuntu-12-04-14-04-64bit-on-my-lenovo-s205#) ,for example.

Comment: This worked in our case. It's possibly why resetting the BIOS to defaults works too.

Answer (score 0):

To quote [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/730868/438156)

> Several things to try
>
> - [`echo "blacklist ideapad_laptop" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ideapad.conf` disables the Lenovo driver module](https://askubuntu.com/a/587760/438156),
>     or
> - [reset the bios](https://askubuntu.com/a/449293/438156):
>
>   > [Hit F2 to enter bios, then F9 to reset, then F10 to save and exit. Your wireless should be working at that point.](http://thetarah.com/2012/10/18/lenovo-z570-phy0-hard-blocked-solution/)